# Which one of the UIImage's blendmode is equal to the SRCINVERT of the bitblt?

Tags: objective-c

I want to XOR the destination image with the source image. 
I think  that UIImage's blendmode is the right way.
I try kCGBlendModeXOR, But failed.

So which one  of  the UIImage's   blendmode  is equal  to the  SRCINVERT of the  bitblt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be out of luck. In the documentation for `kCGBlendModeXOR`, it says:

> `R = S*(1 - Da) + D*(1 - Sa).` This XOR mode is only nominally related to the classical bitmap XOR operation, which is not supported by Quartz 2D.

It looks like you can't do what you want to do by means of the CG blend modes.